# ¿ Como debo hacer un console.log para ver errores de registro a la base de datos?

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, nodejs, formularios, consola

Hola estoy creando una aplicación y a la hora de hacer el registro de usuario no llegan los datos a la base de datos.
¿ Como y donde debo hacer el console.log o debugger para ver los errores?
Se que haciendo console.log o debugger podría ver los errores, pero no se la forma de hacerlo, en que parte hacer el console.log.
Lo hice desde el server en el envió post, pero la consola solo me devuelve : "[Function]"
Desde aquí se envían los datos: `<form class="signup-form" action="/signup" method="POST">`
Muestro el código del server.js y la conexión a la base de datos que tengo en otro módulo.
No se si deberia de mostrar más código para que me den idea de encontrar el porque no llegan los datos a la DB.

```js
// SERVER.JS
let express = require('express');
let aws = require('aws-sdk');
let multer = require('multer');
let multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
let ext = require('file-extension');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let expressSession = require('express-session');
let passport = require('passport');
let michaelgram = require('michaelgram-client')
let config = require('./config');
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

let client = michaelgram.createClient(config.client);

let s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: config.aws.accessKey,
  secretAccessKey: config.aws.secretKey
});

let storage = multerS3({
  s3: s3,
  bucket: 'michaelgram',
  acl: 'public-read',
  metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname })
  },
  key: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, +Date.now() + '.' + ext(file.originalname))
  }
});
let upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('picture');
let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: config.secret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Michaelgram' });
})

app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Michaelgram - Signup' });
})

app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
  let user = req.body;
  client.saveUser(user, function (err, usr) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err.message)
    console.log(app.post)
    res.redirect('/signin');
  });
});

app.get('/signin', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Michaelgram - Signin' });
})

app.get('/api/pictures', function (req, res, next) {
  let pictures = []

  setTimeout(function () {
    res.send(pictures);
  }, 2000)
});

app.post('/api/pictures', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(500, "Error uploading file");
    }
    res.send('File uploaded');
  })
})

app.get('/api/user/:username', (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    username: 'miguelito',
  }

  res.send(user);
})

app.get('/:username', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: `Michaelgram - ${req.params.username}` });
})

app.get('/:username/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: `Michaelgram - ${req.params.username}` });
})

app.listen(3000, function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log('Hubo un error'), process.exit(1);

  console.log('Michaelgram escuchando en el puerto 3000');
})

// CONEXION A LA DB
const co = require('co')
const r = require('rethinkdb')
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const uuid = require('uuid-base62')
const utils = require('./utils')

const defaults = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 28015,
  db: 'michaelgram'
}

class Db {
  constructor (options) {
    options = options || {}
    this.host = options.host || defaults.host
    this.port = options.port || defaults.port
    this.db = options.db || defaults.db
    this.setup = options.setup || false
  }

  connect (callback) {
    this.connection = r.connect({
      host: this.host,
      port: this.port
    })

    this.connected = true

    let db = this.db
    let connection = this.connection

    if (!this.setup) {
      return Promise.resolve(connection).asCallback(callback)
    }

    let setup = co.wrap(function * () {
      let conn = yield connection
      let dbList = yield r.dbList().run(conn)
      if (dbList.indexOf(db) === -1) {
        yield r.dbCreate(db).run(conn)
      }

      let dbTables = yield r.db(db).tableList().run(conn)
      if (dbTables.indexOf('images') === -1) {
        yield r.db(db).tableCreate('images').run(conn)
        yield r.db(db).table('images').indexCreate('createdAt').run(conn)
        yield r.db(db).table('images').indexCreate('userId', { multi: true }).run(conn)
      }

      if (dbTables.indexOf('users') === -1) {
        yield r.db(db).tableCreate('users').run(conn)
        yield r.db(db).table('users').indexCreate('username').run(conn)
      }

      return conn
    })

    return Promise.resolve(setup()).asCallback(callback)
  }

  disconnect (callback) {
    if (!this.connected) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('not connected')).asCallback(callback)
    }

    this.connected = false
    return Promise.resolve(this.connection)
      .then((conn) => conn.close())
  }

  saveImage (image, callback) {
    if (!this.connect) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('not connected')).asCallback(callback)
    }
    let connection = this.connection
    let db = this.db

    let tasks = co.wrap(function * () {
      let conn = yield connection
      image.createdAt = new Date()
      image.tags = utils.extractTags(image.description)

      let result = yield r.db(db).table('images').insert(image).run(conn)

      if (result.errors > 0) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(result.first_error))
      }

      image.id = result.generated_keys[0]

      yield r.db(db).table('images').get(image.id).update({
        publicId: uuid.encode(image.id)
      }).run(conn)

      let created = yield r.db(db).table('images').get(image.id).run(conn)

      return Promise.resolve(created)
    })

    return Promise.resolve(tasks()).asCallback(callback)
  }

  likeImage (id, callback) {
    if (!this.connect) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('not connected')).Callback(callback)
    }

    let connection = this.connection
    let db = this.db
    let getImage = this.getImage.bind(this)

    let tasks = co.wrap(function * () {
      let conn = yield connection
      let image = yield getImage(id)
      yield r.db(db).table('images').get(image.id).update({
        liked: true,
        likes: image.likes + 1
      }).run(conn)

      let created = yield getImage(id)
      return Promise.resolve(created)
    })

    return Promise.resolve(tasks()).asCallback(callback)
  }

  getImage (id, callback) {
    if (!this.connect) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('not connected')).Callback(callback)
    }

    let connection = this.connection
    let db = this.db
    let imageId = uuid.decode(id)

    let tasks = co.wrap(function * () {
      let conn = yield connection
      let image = yield r.db(db).table('images').get(imageId).run(conn)
      if (!image) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(`image ${imageId} not found`))
      }
      return Promise.resolve(image)
    })

    return Promise.resolve(tasks()).asCallback(callback)
  }

  getImages (callback) {
    if (!this.connected) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('not connected')).Callback(callback)
    }

    let connection = this.connection
    let db = this.db

    let tasks = co.wrap(function * () {
      let conn = yield connection

      let images = yield r.db(db).table('images').orderBy({
        index: r.desc('createdAt')
      }).run(conn)

      let result = yield images.toArray()

      return Promise.resolve(result)
    })
    return Promise.resolve(tasks()).asCallback(callback)
  }

  saveUser (user, callback) {
    if (!this.connected) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('not connected')).Callback(callback)
    }

    let connection = this.connection
    let db = this.db

    let tasks = co.wrap(function * () {
      let conn = yield connection
      user.password = utils.encrypt(user.password)
      user.createdAt = new Date()

      let result = yield r.db(db).table('users').insert(user).run(conn)
      if (result.errors > 0) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(result.first_error))
      }

      user.id = result.generated_keys[0]

      let created = yield r.db(db).table('users').get(user.id).run(conn)

      return Promise.resolve(created)
    })

    return Promise.resolve(tasks()).asCallback(callback)
  }

  getUser (username, callback) {
    if (!this.connected) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('not connected')).Callback(callback)
    }

    let connection = this.connection
    let db = this.db

    let tasks = co.wrap(function * () {
      let conn = yield connection
      yield r.db(db).table('users').indexWait().run(conn)
      let users = yield r.db(db).table('users').getAll(username, {
        index: 'username'
      }).run(conn)

      let result = null
      try {
        result = yield users.next()
      } catch (e) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(`user ${username} not found`))
      }

      return Promise.resolve(result)
    })

    return Promise.resolve(tasks()).asCallback(callback)
  }

  authenticate (username, password, callback) {
    if (!this.connected) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('not connected')).Callback(callback)
    }

    let getUser = this.getUser.bind(this)

    let tasks = co.wrap(function * () {
      let user = null
      try {
        user = yield getUser(username)
      } catch (e) {
        return Promise.resolve(false)
      }
      if (user.password === utils.encrypt(password)) {
        return Promise.resolve(true)
      }

      return Promise.resolve(false)
    })
    return Promise.resolve(tasks()).asCallback(callback)
  }

  getImagesByUser (userId, password, callback) {
    if (!this.connected) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('not connected')).Callback(callback)
    }

    let connection = this.connection
    let db = this.db

    let tasks = co.wrap(function * () {
      let conn = yield connection

      yield r.db(db).table('images').indexWait().run(conn)
      let images = yield r.db(db).table('images').getAll(userId, {
        index: 'userId'
      }).orderBy(r.desc('createdAt')).run(conn)

      let result = yield images.toArray()

      return Promise.resolve(result)
    })

    return Promise.resolve(tasks()).asCallback(callback)
  }

  getImagesByTag (tag, callback) {
    if (!this.connected) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('not connected')).Callback(callback)
    }

    let connection = this.connection
    let db = this.db
    tag = utils.normalize(tag)

    let tasks = co.wrap(function * () {
      let conn = yield connection

      yield r.db(db).table('images').indexWait().run(conn)
      let images = yield r.db(db).table('images').filter((img) => {
        return img('tags').contains(tag)
      }).orderBy(r.desc('createdAt')).run(conn)

      let result = yield images.toArray()

      return Promise.resolve(result)
    })

    return Promise.resolve(tasks()).asCallback(callback)
  }
}

module.exports = Db

//ENVIO DESDE EL MODULO API
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'
let db = new Db(config.db)

  if (env === 'test') {
    db = new DbStub()
}

const hash = HttpHash()

hash.set('POST /', async function saveUser (req, res, params) {
  let user = await json(req)
  await db.connect()
  let created = await db.saveUser(user)
  await db.disconnect()

  delete created.password
  delete created.email

  send(res, 201, created)
})

hash.set('GET /:username', async function getUser (req, res, params) {
  let username = params.username
  await db.connect()
  let user = await db.getUser(username)
  await db.disconnect()

  delete user.password
  delete user.email

  send(res, 200, user)
})

export default async function main (req, res) {
  let { method, url } = req
  let match = hash.get(`${method.toUpperCase()} ${url}`)

  if (match.handler) {
    try {
      await match.handler(req, res, match.params)
    } catch (e) {
      send(res, 500, { error: e.message })
    }
  } else {
    send(res, 404, { error: 'route not found' })
  }
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Yo he utilizado log's con console.log() en librerías [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) y [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) sin problemas, no se si te sirva el ejemplo de la forma en que lo he realizado.

Comment: Gracias @ValVert , en este caso utilizo Rethinkdb. El problema es que quiza no formule bien la pregunta. Quiero aprender a descubrir los errores con debug o console.log()